# (Gatsby-Strapi) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, strapi, gatsby-plugin

I want to follow the instruction :https://strapi.io/blog/building-a-static-website-using-gatsby-and-strapi#allowaccess

But encounter Error: Request failed with status code 404

Node.js version:
v10.13.0
npm version:
6.14.6
Strapi version:
3.1.0-alpha.5
Operating system:
mac

Which example is causing problem?
strapi.io/blog/building-a-static-website-using-gatsby-and-strapi#allowaccess

What is the current behavior?
Graphql Query doesn't work.

the steps to reproduce the problem:

```
$ gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs
success load plugins - 2.011s
success onPreInit - 0.004s
success initialize cache - 0.018s
success copy gatsby files - 0.102s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.017s
success createSchemaCustomization -
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi
info Starting to fetch data from Strapi

ERROR #11321 PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Request failed with status code 404

Error: Request failed with status code 404

createError.js:16 createError
[portfolio_v4]/[gatsby-source-strapi ]/[axios]/lib/core/createError.js:16 :15

settle.js:18 settle
[portfolio_v4]/[gatsby-source-strapi ]/[axios]/lib/core/settle.js:18:12

http.js:202 IncomingMessage.handleSt reamEnd
[portfolio_v4]/[gatsby-source-strapi ]/[axios]/lib/adapters/http.js:202:1 1

task_queues.js:84 processTicksAndRej ections
internal/process/task_queues.js:84:2 1
```

What is the expected behavior?
What is the expected behavior?

Doesn't work when I try to get from gatsby
http://localhost:8000/___graphql

There is no method allStrapiblogs on http://localhost:8000/___graphql

Comment: Can you share your `gatsby-config.js`? Especially the Strapi filesystem and connection part.

Answer (score 1):

Please share your gatsby-config.js screen, the `gatsby-source-strapi` section.

this could be caused by the collectionTypes/singleTypes in the `gatsby-source-strapi`, or your USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN (roles) in strapi is not set

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29789565)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed `contentTypes`  to `collectionTypes`

Also there is a new **version (v4)** of [strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/announcing-strapi-v4) and to make gatsby work with this new version, you need to use the following [gatsby-source](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/@relate-app/gatsby-source-strapi/?=gatsby-source-str) plugin.

```
npm install --save gatsby-source-strapi@relate-app/gatsby-source-strapi
```

This plugin wants a token which you can create at http://localhost:1337/admin/settings/api-tokens

before testing the new plugin make sure to clean out your gatsby cache by using the following command:
`gatsby clean`

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
  options: {
    apiURL: "http://localhost:1337",
    collectionTypes: ["Article", "User", 'Test'],
    // Extract images from markdown fields.
    markdownImages: {
      typesToParse: {
        Article: ["body"],
        ComponentBlockBody: ["text"],
      },
    },
    // Only include specific locale.
    locale: "en", // default to all
    // Include drafts in build.
    preview: true, // defaults to false
    // Use application token.
    token:
      'Your-strapi-api-token',
    // Add additional headers.
    headers: {},
  },
},
```

There has also been a article about a new plugin, but this refers to another one which didn't work for me.
https://strapi.io/blog/introducing-the-new-gatsby-source-strapi-plugin

Comment: Excellent, 2 days looking for a solution, this plugin works, the others in the gatsby docs dont work with images in V4

Comment: I must add that for some reason the plugin won't work in production mode for me. Don't know if this is the case for everyone.

Comment: It works fine for me, gatsby-config.js   {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-strapi',
      options: {
        apiURL: 'http://localhost:1337',
        collectionTypes: ['paginas'],
        singleTypes: ['principal',"servicio"],
        // Extract images from markdown fields.
        // markdownImages: {
        //   typesToParse: {
        //     Article: ['body'],
        //     ComponentBlockBody: ['text'],
        //   },
        // },
        // Only include specific locale.
        locale: 'es', 
        preview: false, 
        token: 'xx',
      },
    },

Answer (score 0):

When added "${DOMAIN}/api" on apiURL it worked for me with strapi v4

> apiURL: "http://localhost:1337/api",

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
  options: {
    apiURL: "http://localhost:1337/api",
    collectionTypes: [`messages`],
    // Extract images from markdown fields.
    markdownImages: {
      typesToParse: {
        Article: ["body"],
        ComponentBlockBody: ["text"],
      },
    },
    // Only include specific locale.
    locale: "en", // default to all
    // Include drafts in build.
    preview: true, // defaults to false
    // Use application token.
    token: "token",
    // Add additional headers.
    headers: {},
  },
},
```

Answer (score -1):

This code solved my problem.

```
{
  resolve:'gatsby-source-strapi',
  options:{
      apiURL:'*http://localhost:1337/admin/content-manager/collectionType/api::*',
     
      collectionTypes: ['propiedads','paginas','categorias'],
      queryLimit:1000
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This failed for me, same error