# ERROR #11321 PLUGIN "gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes

Tags: gatsby, strapi, gatsby-plugin

I am running my strapi on production server, and this is my code in `gatsby-config`:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
      options: {
        apiURL: `http://strapi.myserver.com/api`,
        queryLimit: 1000, // Default to 100
        collectionTypes: [`Career`],
        token: 'mytoken'
      },
    }
```

My apis are working correctly when I go to `http://strapi.myserver.com/api/careers` however `graphiQL` doesn't see them, also when I run `gatsby develop` it throws these errors:

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Request failed with status code 404



ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"@relate-app/gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the createSchemaCustomization lifecycle:

request to http://strapi.myserver.com/api/graphql failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND strapi.myserver.com
```

This answer didn't help: [(Gatsby-Strapi) Error: Request failed with status code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212938/gatsby-strapi-error-request-failed-with-status-code-404)

Also my user permissions all of them are checked, my collections are published.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your API token type to "Full access". Go to  Settings > Global Settings > API Tokens then click on edit icon in at your API Token and then change token type to "Full access".

Answer (score 1):

I've tried what you suggested (the token) but didn't work.
My environment:
Win11

```
"gatsby": "^5.7.0"
"gatsby-source-strapi": "^3.0.6"
strapi project:  "@strapi/strapi": "4.8.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a project with Gatsby - Strapi. And when I tried to connect working Gatsby to Strapi, I had this error:[console.log of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYpsG.png)

At this moment, I had in gatsby project:
"gatsby": "^5.3.3"
"gatsby-source-strapi": "^3.0.4".

And in strapi project:
"@strapi/strapi": "4.5.5",

I used documentation from gatsby, but in addition to them, I have to add this:

1. As a MAC user, I have to use this line in config.json for plugin configuration:
   resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
   options: {
   apiURL: `http://127.0.0.1:1337`,
   collectionTypes: [`jobs`],
   },
   After those lines, I still had a 403 error, but in the browser, I could get a JSON object. To resolve this error, I created API Token, as someone suggested, but with full access. Otherwise, the error doesn't go. I had tried to create a token with read and read one only, but it didn't solve the problem for me.